# How do I re-write logic of returning an empty Mono object in a functional programming style using Java 1.8 and Spring 5

Tags: lambda, java-8, functional-programming, spring-webflux

I have below code which is a mixture of both imperative programming style and functional programming style using Lambda in a Java application built using JDK 1.8 and Spring 5.

public Mono updateEmpDetails(String compId, String userId,
      String city) {

```
logger.info("Entering updateEmpDetails@EmployeeService");

final UserKey userKey = getCommerceObj(compId, userId);
Optional <Employee> emp = EmployeeRepository.findById(userKey);

if (emp.isPresent()) {
  Employee empObj = emp.get();
  empObj.setCity(city);
  final Mono<Employee> Employee = asyncRunner
                .one(() -> EmployeeRepository.saveAndFlush(empObj))                 
                .doOnNext(value -> new CommonService().refreshMap())
      .doOnError(error -> logger.error("Error while persisting Emp User Object: ", error))
      .map(EmployeeObj -> EmployeeObj);
  logger.info("Exiting updateEmpDetails@EmployeeService");
  return Employee;

}else{
    return null;

    }

}
```

I put **if** condition to make sure Employee object is not null in Optional using isPresent().

I want to remove its **return null** check from else condition such that whenever there is an empty Mono of Employee just return empty Mono.  I'm new to lambda and functional programming. please let me know how can re-write this logic and please make me understand as well so that I can do it in future by my own. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`and `orElse` functions like below :

```
public Mono updateEmpDetails(String compId, String userId, String city) {
    logger.info("Entering updateEmpDetails@EmployeeService");
    final UserKey userKey = getCommerceObj(compId, userId);
    Optional <Employee> emp = EmployeeRepository.findById(userKey);
    return emp.map(e -> updateEmployee(e, city)).orElse(Mono.empty());
}

private Mono<Employee> updateEmployee(Employee empObj, String city) {
    empObj.setCity(city);
    final Mono<Employee> Employee = asyncRunner
                .one(() -> EmployeeRepository.saveAndFlush(empObj))                 
                .doOnNext(value -> new CommonService().refreshMap())
      .doOnError(error -> logger.error("Error while persisting Emp User Object: ", error))
      .map(EmployeeObj -> EmployeeObj);
    logger.info("Exiting updateEmpDetails@EmployeeService");
    return Employee;
}
```